# Extract proper values using 3 tables, when null/not null

Tags: sql, sql-server

Have three tables as follows:

tbSubSubKategorie:

```
ID  Name    
1   PodPodKategoria_1   
2   PodPodKategoria_2   
3   PodPodKategoria_3   
4   PodPodKategoria_4   
6   PodPodKategoria_5
```

tbSection

```
Id  Name    
2   Design  
3   Wichtigste Eigenschaften der Stoffe 
4   Pflegehinweis   
5   Funktionen  
6   Sitzkomfort 
7   Abmessungen im Detail   
8   Versand & Montage   
9   Lieferumfang
```

tbSection_SubSubKategorie

```
Id  FK_Section_ID   FK_SubSubKategorie
2   2           2
5   6           2
7   2           3
8   7           3
10  5           2
11  5           3
13  8           NULL
15  3           2
```

In model there could be that one section could be associated with multi diffrent subsubkategories or second case when section is not associated with any subsubkategorie then for this section will be always one record with section id and null value in FK_SubSubKategorie field.

What i would like to achieve now is to get information what are the connections from the table tbSection_SubSubKategorie. I would like to get information:

> tbSection_SubSubKategorie.Id, tbSectionId, tbSection.Name,
>   FK_SubSubKategorie.Name

I have problem when section is associated with null for subsubkategorie.

My current query is built like this:

```
SELECT CASE WHEN section_subsubkategorie.FK_SubSubKategorie IS NULL THEN 'section does not contain subsubkategorie' ELSE convert(varchar(10), section_subsubkategorie.FK_SubSubKategorie, 121)  END AS IDX, *
        FROM tbSection as section
                INNER JOIN tbSection_SubSubKategorie as section_subsubkategorie ON section.Id = section_subsubkategorie.FK_Section_ID
                INNER JOIN tbSubSubKategorie as subkategorie 
                ON section_subsubkategorie.FK_SubSubKategorie = subkategorie.Id OR section_subsubkategorie.FK_SubSubKategorie IS NULL
```

but result is incorrect:

[image]

As you se for section Id 8 i see 4 rows, and should be only one... I even tried to use CASE but still its not THIS. Could you help? Hope you get my point.

[Tables creation code](http://pastebin.com/M8gfN8je)

Comment: Here is a great place to start. http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/

Comment: i added table creations cript. I think problem is easy to solve but so far i am missing something.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace your last `INNER JOIN` with a `LEFT JOIN` and remove the `OR` clause:

```
SELECT CASE WHEN section_subsubkategorie.FK_SubSubKategorie IS NULL THEN 'section does not contain subsubkategorie' ELSE convert(varchar(10), section_subsubkategorie.FK_SubSubKategorie, 121)  END AS IDX, *
        FROM tbSection as section
                INNER JOIN tbSection_SubSubKategorie as section_subsubkategorie ON section.Id = section_subsubkategorie.FK_Section_ID
                LEFT JOIN tbSubSubKategorie as subkategorie 
                ON section_subsubkategorie.FK_SubSubKategorie = subkategorie.Id
```

Right now you're telling it to join only if the two ids match (which they don't since the second is `null`), or to join a `null` to every id separately, which is causing the duplicate lines for each of the first 6 ids.

A `LEFT JOIN` will keep the original line, and simply add `null` to the `FK_SubSubKategorie` field, which will also allow your case statement to work properly for the `IDX` field.

Comment: that was my gap - thanks ! P.S Just for interesting if i would put RIGHT instead of LEFT how you would describe then this behaviour?

Comment: A `LEFT JOIN` will keep all rows from the left table (the table you already referenced in a previous `FROM` or `JOIN`) regardless of whether they have a matching value in the left table.  If they do not have a matching value, the cell will be `null`.  A `RIGHT JOIN` does the opposite, it keeps all rows from the right table (the one you are joining to) and fills the cells of non-matching values from the left table with `null`

Comment: See this link for a much more in-depth explanation, or search SO for some good posts about it http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/33052/Visual-Representation-of-SQL-Joins

Comment: In your case, if you switched to `RIGHT JOIN`, I expect those rows would disappear entirely from your results, since `FK_SubSubKategorie` is `null` and would not `JOIN` to anything from the left table.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly you are getting 5 rows and you want 1. In that case use a `LEFT JOIN` when joining tbSubSubKategorie and remove the `OR` as well.

```
SELECT CASE WHEN section_subsubkategorie.FK_SubSubKategorie IS NULL THEN 'section does not contain subsubkategorie' ELSE convert(varchar(10), section_subsubkategorie.FK_SubSubKategorie, 121)  END AS IDX, *
        FROM tbSection as section
                INNER JOIN tbSection_SubSubKategorie as section_subsubkategorie ON section.Id = section_subsubkategorie.FK_Section_ID
                LEFT JOIN tbSubSubKategorie as subkategorie 
                ON section_subsubkategorie.FK_SubSubKategorie = subkategorie.Id
```